# How to react to the event of GIS information not being shared?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, gis, bing-maps

I'm using the following code ([from this guide](http://www.bingmapsportal.com/isdk/ajaxv7#GetUserLocation5)) to move the user to their current, geographical location. However, although the call-back for success works as supposed to, the one for error doesn't seem to get fired (despite that [#1 in the API states that it should](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh125839.aspx)).

```
var geolocationProvider = new Microsoft.Maps
  .GeoLocationProvider(map).getCurrentPosition({
    successCallback: function (data) { alert("Yey!"); },
    errorCallback: function (data) { alert("Buu!"); },
  ...
});
```

That begs three questions.

1. Can I, and if so how, react to the user clicking not to share the GIS info?
2. Can I, and if so how, react to the user preselecting not to share the GIS info?
3. What event is *errorCallback()* listening to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a timeout for that to work. As mentioned in the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh125839.aspx):

> 3 The time specified in timeout has been exceeded.

By default there is no timeout specified, so unless there is a real error then nothing will ever happen.

> The length of time, in milliseconds, to allow for the geo location request to return. By default there is no timeout.

When the user decided not to share their location information nothing happens. So specify a timeout and then your error message will fire after that amount of time.

Comment: Hmmm... I'd very much prefer to take action upon the user's choice not to disclose their location. But I'd very much prefer to be more handsome than Brad Pitt too. I guess neither one is going to come true, haha. (Please add a link to the docs section that you've quoted, so I can accept your reply as the correct answer.)

Comment: I used the same docs that you linked to in your question, but I added a link as well.